# Sorting foreign key items in the template

Tags: python, jinja2, peewee

The following code works in an application:

```
user.tweets.order_by(Tweet.message)
```

The following code works in a jinja2 template:

```
{% for tweet in user.tweets %}
```

But the following code fails in a template:

```
{% for tweet in user.tweets.order_by(Tweet.message) %}
```

Is there a cleaner way to sort the tweets in a jinja2 template, other than adding the following method to the `User` class?

```
def tweets_by_message(self):
    return user.tweets.order_by(Tweet.message)
```

There is nothing wrong with that method, but adding a little method every time I need a different order doesn't sound right.

Comment: What do you mean at the beginning when you say "The following code works in an application"? What sort of application? Ref the docs for jinja2 filters, I think you need to user the sort filter and the attribute param: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sort

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can drop `Tweet` into the template context. Or better yet, use a context processor to dump all your models into the template context so they're available all the time.

```
@app.context_processor
def _inject_models():
    return {
        'Tweet': Tweet,
        'User': User,
        'Foo': Foo,
    }
```

I don't know if this works, but might be worth a shot?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
{% for tweet in user.tweets|sort(attribute='message') %}
```